# window.open returns undefined on ios/phonegap

Tags: ios, angularjs, cordova

I am writing a phonegap app running angular. Part of the app opens a window in a new tab:

```
let new_window = ctrl.$window.open(super_secret_url, '_blank', 'location=no,toolbar=no'); //get around the popup blocker

new_window.addEventListener('loadstop', (event) => {
    if (event.url.match("/window/close")) {
        new_window.close();

        ctrl.redirect();
    }
});
```

This works fine on android but `new_window` is undefined when running on iOS. (I know the variable is undefined because apparently you can debug a safari tab on an iPad with safari on your PC. Who knew?)

I believe the `undefined` implies some sort of pop-up blocking? But I'm new to this. What would cause it work on android but not ios?

Comment: do you have inAppBrowser plugin installed?

Comment: Thanks! That seems to have fixed the problem for now.